# How to avoid opening a redundant file with vim?

Tags: shell-script

I have a script designed to open files based on dates.

The idea is that if files with different years, but the same day/month exist, open them.

It must also open today's file, whether today exists or not.

Here is the current script

```
#!/bin/bash
TODAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d).md
PAST=$(ls 20??-$(date +%m-%d).md)

if [[ -z "$PAST" ]]; then
  DATE=$TODAY
else
  DATE=$PAST
fi

nvim -O $DATE $TODAY
```

The problem here of course is that if today's file already exists, then vim will open two instances of it. And if I don't add that last $TODAY, then today's file won't be created if it doesn't exist. I'm struggling to come up with an elegant solution to this problem that doesn't rely on convoluted if instances.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
  if [[ $PAST != *"$TODAY"* ]]; then
    DATE="$PAST $TODAY"
  else
    DATE="$PAST"
  fi

  nvim -O $DATE
```